# How to compare version in feature branch against master branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab-ci, cicd

In our organization, we follow distributed version control policy using Git. We have a master branch and some feature branches. When a feature is released that branch is merged into master. I need to apply comparison between feature branch gradle properties version against master. I need to ensure The version in feature branch must be greater than the master branch. How can we write some scripts in build gradle or CICD git yml.  If version matched the build should get failed automatically.

Example:
Master has version 0.0.1 then features version should be 0.0.2 or higher.

Does Git have any utility for this?

Comment: `git diff master branch -- gradle.properties`

Comment: Where do we specify this. Can we add it pipeline file or build gradle